# The floor mysteriously disappears in final render

Tags: objects

[image: Object "plane" disappears in final render. Its particles are still appeared. You can see the gray hdr floor.]

I have checked everything but it is only appeared in viewport render.
[image: The object "plane" appears in viewport render but not in final render. Even though the camera icon is on and render visibility is checked.]

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: make sure that the Show Emitter is activated in the Particles panel > Render?